# The EntitySet name 'xxxxx_dk_dbEntities.Vehicle' could not be found

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I use a mssql 2008 server (at my webhotel) and I am trying to save data in it from my code.

I have made this little test code here that gives me this error in topic

```
 Context = new XXX_dk_dbEntities();
 var vehicle = new Vehicle { Name = "test" };
 Context.AddObject("Units", vehicle);
 Context.SaveChanges();
```

EDIT: Changing Context.AddObject(vehicle.GetType().Name, vehicle); to Context.AddObject("Something", vehicle); gives the same error, so I think it might be my connectionstring or my EF that needs proper setup, anyway I can test that?

Edit 2: Changed it to Units now which makes my error {"The underlying provider failed on Open."} and inspecting that gives me this error  {"Login failed for user 'xxxxx_dk'."} so it must be my connectionstring

```
<add name="xxxxx_dk_dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Areas.Units.UnitsModel.csdl|res://*/Areas.Units.UnitsModel.ssdl|res://*/Areas.Units.UnitsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=mssql1.unoeuro.com;initial catalog=xxxxxxx_dk_db;persist security info=True;user id=xxxxxxxx_dk;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is the solutionexplore showing my edmx structure [image: http://www.gratisimage.dk/graphic/images/2011/November/02/7BBD_4EB183FB.jpg]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but if there arent a entity set name, I dont think you can add it. Seems like a vehicle is a special kind of unit. Arent there are enity set defined on your context ?

Comment: Iam not sure, I havent done it, thought the EF took care of most it automaticly?

Comment: Never the less, it needs a place to "save" the additional information that on the vehicle. Only place I can think of is a table. That does AddObject not just take an object? So its does all the work for you when trying to save it? Seems like a lot of hassel to control the Entity like that. Also ... how would you ever get a vehicle back from the database ?

Comment: Is the `EntitySet` name `Vehicle` or `Vehicles`? You can check this if you right-click on the Vehicle entity in the EF designer and choose Properties. Among them you should see a property named `Entity Set Name`. You can also test by doing `Context.AddObject(" xxxxx_dk_dbEntities.Vehicles", vehicle);`.

Comment: The Set Name is Units and if I use that I get "The underlying provider failed on Open." so that must be a step in the right direction and the inner exception is "{"Login failed for user 'xxxxx_dk'."}" so it must be my connectionstring

Comment: Yes, this error message indicates a problem with your connection string. I don't see any password in yours. You should specify one unless you are using integrated security.

Comment: Yes I think it asked me if I wanted to show password when it generated the connectionstring, so I think if I add that it will work, but I am at work now so gotta try when I get home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I found I had to add the remove  (For some reason it uses a connectionstring specified in machine.config) and changed the name of my own provider to "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" I created a new connectionstring for this to use so remove old connectionstring (Wierd!), create a custom memberprovider like

```
<membership>
  <providers>
      <add connectionStringName="unoeurotest" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

And then make a connectionstring only for this

```
<add name="unoeurotest" connectionString="Data Source=mssql1.unoeuro.com;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx_dk_db;User Id=xxxxx_dk;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"/>
```